# Trigger for INSERT, INSERTS multiple rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am creating a trigger that will insert data into tableB after I manually insert data into tableA.

My current issue is that after inserting multiple rows into tableA, tableB will create more rows than needed.

E.g. Inserting 3 rows of data into tableA will result in the trigger inserting 6 rows into tableB. The issue seems to be the trigger tracking every row in tableA for every insert.

The trigger is as follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT ON tableA 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tableB(cust_id, name)
    SELECT new.cust_id, new.name FROM tableA;
```

The output both tables, that results from the 3 inserts into tableA are as follows.

tableA

| cust_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Frodo |
| 0002 | Sam |
| 0003 | Merry |

tableB

| cust_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Frodo |
| 0002 | Sam |
| 0002 | Sam |
| 0003 | Merry |
| 0003 | Merry |
| 0003 | Merry |

I am currently looking for a way to have 1 row from tableA create 1 row into tableB and have similar amount of rows into both the tables.

Would be thankful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each row - means for each row inserted so instead of insert..select insert..values is more appropriate

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT ON tableA 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tableB(cust_id, name) values(new.cust_id, new.name);
```